# saving screenshots from before OS is installed

Tags: filesystem, files, screenshot

I'm doing an assignment which requires me to take screenshots of everything I do, including taking screenshots of using using the partition manager in the "test" version of Ubuntu 12.10.

How can I permanently save these somewhere so I don't lose them once I restart my computer to use the full version of Ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a flash drive?

Comment: i get the error "Operation not supported by backend" when i try to copy them from the desktop to any drive including a usb

Comment: Can you manually mount another hard drive partition?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a cloud service like Ubuntu One for this! I'm not sure if file sync would work from the live CD, but you could open the Ubuntu One web interface in Firefox and upload your files to it there. If you don't have an Ubuntu One account, you can register for one at https://one.ubuntu.com/ - it's free and already built into the installation of Ubuntu 12.10 you'll have once you're done installing.

Or, if you use another cloud service (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc), Firefox on the Live CD should be able to access those too.

Good luck!

Comment: I can't connect to the internet with either a wired or wireless connection either :/ i thought of doing that or emailing. I saved it to the windows partition of my hard drive but im not 100% sure that the files will be written when i restart the computer and i really cant afford to lose the files